# Retrieving the users from Azure tenant using Graph API getObjectsByObjectIds method

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I went to Azure portal -> Active Directory -> App registrations to create an App. And I have given few permission to Microsoft Graph API and Azure active directory API

Then I am trying to retrieve the users from Azure Tenant. I am using graph API retrieve the Users. PFB is the URL i am using

[https://graph.windows.net/AzureTenantIdhere/getObjectsByObjectIds?api-version=1.6](https://graph.windows.net/AzureTenantIdHere/getObjectsByObjectIds?api-version=1.6)

I am getting **403: Forbidden error** When i was trying above URL. I know this error is due to the permissions of the App(Above created)

Can some please let me know what all the permissions i need to give the App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your App need a required permission with **Microsoft Graph** called `Directory.Read.All`, refer to this [article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryobject_getbyids).

The Display String in AAD called `Read directory data`, just give the permission. 
You could refer to this [article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#directory-permissions).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Joy. I need only one permission for Read directory data, that is all?

Comment: Yes, you could refer to the article I mentioned.